# Can I save unit keyword into a variable in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, stored-functions

I would like to write a procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `addByType`(IN myDate DATETIME, IN myType INT, OUT output DATETIME)
BEGIN
DECLARE unit ?;
CASE  
    WHEN myType = 1 THEN 
        SET unit = HOUR;        
    WHEN myType = 2 THEN
        SET unit = DAY;
    ...
END CASE;
SELECT TIMESTAMPADD(unit, 1, myDate) INTO output;
END
```

Is it possible somehow? Can I store unit keyword into variable? Or is there another way to achieve the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a try with this one:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `addByType`(IN myDate DATETIME, IN myType INT, OUT output DATETIME)
BEGIN

CASE  
    WHEN myType = 1 THEN 
        SET @unit = 'HOUR';        
    WHEN myType = 2 THEN
        SET @unit = 'DAY';
END CASE;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT TIMESTAMPADD(', @unit, ', 1, \'', myDate, '\') INTO @output;');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
SET output = @output;

END
```

May include syntax errors, would have to look up certain things. But I'm sure you can figure it out. Gotta go now, will have a look again tomorrow.

P.S: [Here's the manual entry for prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I edited out some minor issues from your code, but otherwise it works perfectly for me.
I'm not sure why I had to introduce @output variable, but I get "ERROR 1327 (42000): Undeclared variable: output" without it.

Comment: I found the reason: 
"Local variables are in scope only during stored program execution. References to them are not permitted within prepared statements because those are global to the current session and the variables might have gone out of scope when the statement is executed." (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/local-variable-scope.html)